# Get the element whose click opened a Bootstrap Modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I know which button triggered the opening of a Bootstrap Modal Dialog?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Button 1
</a>  
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Button 2
</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  var triggerElement = ???
})
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var triggerElement = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
});
```

**Edit:**
As noted in comments, if buttons are dynamically generated we can attach an event listener to document:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#myModal', function (event) {
     var triggerElement = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that the buttons are dynamically generated, so this didn't work. I ended up doing `$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#myModal', function (event) {...}`

Comment: @FrancescoLorenzetti84 Ok, I will update answer to cover this case too

Comment: I found that 'shown.bs.modal' adds a delay, so to avoid this we should use 'show.bs.modal'.